# How we design themes using drupal

Tags: theming, hooks

I am new to drupal cms, can any one tell me how we design themes using drupal.

Comment: See the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme)

Comment: By the way, this question is way too broad for Drupal Answers. Have a read of the official Drupal documentation, and if you have specific questions bring them back here and you'll get some good responses

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7 ?

Comment: See the [faq]. You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating sub-themes by following the procedure given [here](http://drupal.org/node/225125).
Modifying is easier then creating a new theme from scratch(my experience). For this you will need to select a base theme, which you can download from [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/project/themes). The most common theme which is used to create sub-themes is [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen).

Here is nice [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0i5P3QGm5s) which will help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 7 you can use [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme.
It's an html5 template with responsive grid. it includes media queries (it helps you building different layout for screen and mobile device.
[Here](http://drupal.org/node/1440250) you can find the documentation.

You can also follow indrock's suggestion. Zen now has got the HTML5 as well.